# Store results of find in a file or variable each match on one line

Tags: bash, find

I want to store matches of a find command into a file or variable, but matches should go into separate lines.

When I do `files=$(find ./ -type f [match criteria])` then the matches will be separated by one space when I see the `echo $files` output:

```
./mounts.sh ./delete-data.sh ./test.sh
```

How can I store one result per line instead?

Comment: You very seldom need to store separate pathnames in a single string. I'm assuming you want to _use_ the pathnames for something? If so, that could be done directly from `find`.  Note too that `echo` outputs each of its arguments with spaces between them, and you're giving it a string for the shell to split up into multiple arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes I know I can directly do stuff with -exec, but I need to store the results in a file or variable in this particular case

Comment: You already do. The issue is that you're not quoting the string you use with `echo`.